# from google.cloud import firestore ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine

I am unable to get my application working reading documents from Google Firestore.

Here is my python Flask main.py

```
from flask import Flask
from google.cloud import firestore

app = Flask(__name__)
db = firestore.Client()

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    posts_ref = db.collections(u'posts')
    posts = posts_ref.get()
    for post in posts:
        return u'{} => {}'.format(post.id, post.to_dict())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

However the logs are showing the following error.

```
2019-02-22 12:33:08 default[2-9]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502
2019-02-22 12:33:10 default[2-9]  [2019-02-22 12:33:10 +0000] [8] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2019-02-22 12:33:10 default[2-9]  [2019-02-22 12:33:10 +0000] [8] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (8)
2019-02-22 12:33:10 default[2-9]  [2019-02-22 12:33:10 +0000] [8] [INFO] Using worker: threads
2019-02-22 12:33:10 default[2-9]  [2019-02-22 12:33:10 +0000] [23] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 23
2019-02-22 12:33:10 default[2-9]  [2019-02-22 12:33:10 +0000] [23] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-02-22 12:33:10 default[2-9]  Traceback (most recent call last):    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py",l
ine 583, in spawn_worker      worker.init_process()    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 104,
 in init_process      super(ThreadWorker, self).init_process()    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py",li
ne 129, in init_process      self.load_wsgi()    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_
wsgi      self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi      self.cal
lable = self.load()    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load      return self.load_wsgiap
p()    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp      return util.import_app(self.app
_uri)    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app      __import__(module)    File "/srv/main
.py", line 2, in <module>      from google.cloud import firestore  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
2019-02-22 12:33:10 default[2-9]  [2019-02-22 12:33:10 +0000] [23] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 23)
2019-02-22 12:33:11 default[2-9]  [2019-02-22 12:33:11 +0000] [8] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

My directory structure

[image]

I have **init**.py in lib folder and in google folder.

Comment: What is the contents of your `requirements.txt` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dustin-ingram@ suggests, it's probable that you've not imported the [`google.cloud.firestore`](https://pypi.org/project/Flask/) (and possibly [`flask`](https://pypi.org/project/Flask/)) packages correctly.

A good practice is to create a virtualenv, a `requirements.txt` and then `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Its contents may be:

```
flask==1.0.2
google-cloud-firestore==0.31.0
```

You've also a typo in your code; it's `collection` not `collections`:

```py
posts_ref = db.collection(u'posts')
```

You will need to have enabled Firestore in your project (and possibly created the `posts` collection before you run your code too).